# React Native - Data Grid for android

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJDWr.png) I'm working with React Native and am looking for an appropriate component for react native data grid. Do you have any recommendation for a data grid under React Native?

Comment: Are you talking about Grid Layout of android?

Comment: data grid layout

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [this](https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid), works very well.